# Performance de substituição em string

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer algumas operações de substituição em massa com Javascript. Para o meu problema específico, vamos supor que preciso substituir uma substring específica. Preciso trocar cada ocorrência de "azul" por "verde".

Então, tenho duas formas de fazer:

```
var foo = pegaTexto(); // imagine que isso retorna uma string qualquer;
foo = foo.replace("azul", "verde");
```

Ou:

```
var foo = pegaTexto();
foo = foo.replace(new RegExp("azul"), "verde");
```

A meu ver, numa situação dessas, a única utilidade prática de se utilizar uma expressão regular seria para especificar uma *flag* (para dizer por exemplo se a busca deve ser global), mas no meu caso estou omitindo as *flags* do construtor  da expressão.

Tenho uma dúvida, no entanto, com relação a performance dessas duas formas distintas.

Forçar o uso de expressão regular provoca algum impacto na performance?

Como eu posso medir isso?

Comment: http://jsperf.com/teste-de-replace

Comment: @Sergio muitíssimo obrigado! Isso vale uma resposta, se você a fizer, terei o prazer de pontuar e marcar como correta :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Você pode usar o **[jsperf.com](http://jsperf.com/)**, aí é possivel montar testes para testar variações diferentes.

Fiz [**um teste**](http://jsperf.com/teste-de-replace) e deu-me 13~15% mais lento com RegExp.

O código que usei:

```
var texto = 'amarelo verde encarnado azul branco';

// com regex    
var regex = new RegExp("azul");
for(var i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
   var resultado = texto.replace(regex, "verde");
}

// com replace de string
for(var i = 0; i < 50000; i++){
   var resultado = texto.replace("azul", "verde");
}
```

A maneira mais rápida para esta função parece contudo ser o split/join - partir a string a cada palavra e voltar a juntar com a palavra nova. Crédito para a [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5239/129) do @utluiz.

```
var novaString = texto.split('palavraAntiga').join('palavraNova');
```

Comment: Não conhecia o `jsperf`, muito obrigado :) fico a imaginar que a operação com `RegExp` seja mais lenta devido ao tempo perdido com a operação de construção do objeto de expressão regular.

Comment: @Renan, fiz um update: http://jsperf.com/teste-de-replace

Comment: Em tempo: mesmo construindo a expressão regular fora do laço e reaproveitando um único objeto todas as cinquenta mil vezes, a expressão regular ainda é mais lenta.

Comment: Se colocar o 'new RegExp("azul")' para fora do for fica mais rápido, mas, ainda sim, é mais lento que o 'replace("azul", "verde")'.

Comment: @Sergio Adicionei a revisão em http://jsperf.com/teste-de-replace/3. Aqui ficou 13% mais lenta. Se puder, atualize a resposta.

Comment: @LucasNunes, obrigado. Actualizei.

Comment: @Sergio revisei seu teste, removendo o loop interno: http://jsperf.com/teste-de-replace/5
Acontece que o loop também estava sendo testado, no caso o desempenho do loop também caia na avaliação o que prejudica o resultado, sendo que o jsperf já faz uma série de repetições de teste do algorítimo, quanto mais isolado mais preciso o resultado.

Comment: @GabrielGartz, boa! interessante ver o split/join também na corrida :)

Comment: Fiquei **surpreso** com o fato de que o método mais performático varia tanto de um navegador para outro!

Answer (score 7):

Acrescentei mais duas técnicas de substituição **que não usam expressões regulares** ao [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/teste-de-replace/5) original do Sergio.

### split/join

```js
var resultado = texto.split('azul').join('verde');
```

### indexOf

```js
var pos = texto.indexOf('azul');
var ultpos = 0;
var resultado = '';
while (pos >= 0) {
    resultado += texto.substring(ultpos, pos) + 'verde';
    ultpos = pos + 4;
    pos = texto.indexOf('azul', pos + 4);
}
if (ultpos < texto.length) {
    resultado += texto.substring(ultpos, texto.length);
}
```

### Resultados

Analisando os resultados em outros navegadores por outros usuários, notei que não existem um consenso sobre o método mais rápido.

Veja o gráfico no momento em que escrevo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Em resumo:

- `split/join` ganha no Chrome
- `indexOf` ganha no Firefox e no Ópera
- `regex` ganha no IE :/

Comment: Interessante, eu não tinha pensado em usar split e join dessa forma. Fico surpreso. +1.

Comment: Boa ideia trazer o split/join para a "corrida" `+1`!