# Removendo caracteres com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

É possível remover um caractere específico com jquery?
Eu estou querendo remover o caractere • 'bolinha em caractere que esta no banco de dados de um site que estou reformular.
Ou seja, eu tenho acesso a todas os HTMLs e CSSs menos ao conteúdo. Com isso a minha lista já tem um Style especifico mas no banco de dados tem esse maldito caractere • digitado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) não possui algumas regras básicas que podem ser resolvidas tranquilamento com javascript como conversões de tipo de dado, identificação de tipo de dado, arredondamento de valor e substituição de strings.

Sendo assim você pode resolver esta situação com javascript:

```js
var str = "• Este é um texto de teste!•••";
var res = str.replace(/•/g, "");

document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = res;
```

```html
<span id="texto"></span>
```

Para resolver este mesmo problema com jQuery seria da seguinte forma

```js
var str = $("#texto").text();
var res = str.replace(/•/g, "");

$("#texto").text(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="texto">• Este é um texto de teste!•••</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use uma expressão regular:

```
var mystring = "• este é um teste"
mystring.replace(/•/g , "");
```

Você pode pegar e alterar o conteúdo com `$('seletor').html()`. A vantagem de usar a expressão regular em vez do replace() é que o replace() só troca a primeira ocorrência.

Answer (score 3):

Podes usar o [.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) para partir a string e depois voltar a juntar com o [.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
"•bolinhas • bolinhas•".split('•').join(''); // dá "bolinhas  bolinhas"
```

Usar o split/join [é mais rápido que usando expressões regulares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5139/129).

Assim podes fazer uma função para limpar strings:

```
function limparBolinhas(str){
    return str.split('•').join('');
}
```

e usar no código consoante precisar.